# Escaping and storing string to mysql in Zend Framework without adding backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to store data to my database as is. Meaning I do not want to add backslashes to single or double quotes. My code is the following

```
$name = "Mike's Coffee House";  
$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->_dbTable->org." SET name = ".$this->_db->quote($name)." WHERE id='1'";
$this->_db->query($sql);
```

My data gets saved as:

```
Mike\'s Coffee House
```

How do I get it to save without the backslashes?

```
Mike's Coffee House
```

This is a 5.2.17 PHP application using ZendFramework 1.6.2 and MySQL

Comment: So you want to escape characters... without escaping characters? Or do you mean remove backslashes once you pull out the data out of the database?

Comment: I need to escape them to not cause an error in the sql query. But I do not want to store the backslashes. If there is another way to "escape" the query without causing an error and not adding backslashes that will solve my issue but I do not know of such way to do so.

Comment: Sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on? I assume your real code is taking values in $_GET or $_POST, not a literal string as shown in your example. You really need to turn off magic quotes.

Comment: magic quotes are off get_magic_quotes_gpc()

Comment: Then can you post the relevant part of your real code? The slashes are coming from somewhere. You are also using very old versions of both ZF  and PHP.

Comment: I think you will need to provide a) a `var_dump()` of the variable that gets passed to the escaping code i.e. the variable that gets passed to `$this->_db->quote(...)`, and b) a `var_dump()` of the `$sql` variable. This will show a) if the variable is already escaped, and b) if the escaping, i.e. `$this->_db->quote(...)` is properly escaping the sql query. If everything is fine with the above, then look at what is happening to the `$sql` variable *before* it gets passed to `$this->_db->query($sql);`. If the answer is nothing. Are you sure? :). It's a process of elimination.

Comment: Also, how do you know that your data gets saved as `Mike\'s Coffee House` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Should work with

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->_dbTable->org." SET name = ".$this->_db->quote(stripslashes($name))." WHERE id='1'";
```

Slashes might already be added (magic quotes might be on).

Using `stripslashes` would only fix this case, but disabling magic quotes would be a full fix.

Comment: This is not good advices as it masks the underlying problem and makes the code less portable.

Comment: As @Bill Karwin mentioned, please check if magic quotes is turned on.

Comment: @OsvyG, stripslashes works like explained in http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php My answer assumes $name is already `Mike\'s Coffee House` when you run `$this->_db->quote` on it, so they need to be removed before being added again by the `quote` function. A better solution would be to modify `quote` function and run `stripslashes` there, so this will work for all cases. If this answer is not clear enough, please specify more about where your variables are taken from and how they look before running `quote` function on them

Comment: @TimFountain, the `quote` function could be modified to see if magic quotes are on, or for some reason the variable already has slashes. Instead of using `quote(stripslashes($name))`, stripslashes will be inside `quote`. I was suggesting a solution that can fix the problem the user has, and can be a starting point for fixing it completely, in the rest of the application.